# Regex to parse docker tag?

Tags: regex

```
'registry/rabbit',
'registry/rabbit:3',
'rabbit',
'rabbit:3'
```

Trying to come up with a regex that will match `rabbit` in the four cases above. Seems easy enough, but my regex-fu is failing me.

Comment: `(?:[a-z]+/)?([a-z]+)(?::[0-9]+)?` you need to read the spec to replace a-z and 0-9 to all possible characters

Comment: Thanks @YOU! `(?:.+/)?([^:]+)(?::.+)?` did the trick. Post as an answer so I can accept it. ;)

Comment: posted, sorry for  late

Comment: Regular expressions are not hard, but they do require a little study. You should try to solve the problem before asking, then show us what you tried

Comment: Below, I assumed Python regexes.  Can you let us know which flavor of regex you'd prefer?  (JavaScript, Perl, etc)

Comment: you can pick the regex patterns from this file. https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/reference/regexp.go

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The format is a little under-specified, but this seems to work:

```
^(?:(?=[^:\/]{1,253})(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)(?:\.(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-))*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?/)?((?![._-])(?:[a-z0-9._-]*)(?<![._-])(?:/(?![._-])[a-z0-9._-]*(?<![._-]))*)(?::(?![.-])[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,128})?$
```

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/):

> An image name is made up of slash-separated name components, optionally prefixed by a registry hostname. The hostname must comply with standard DNS rules, but may not contain underscores. If a hostname is present, it may optionally be followed by a port number in the format :8080. If not present, the command uses Docker’s public registry located at registry-1.docker.io by default. Name components may contain lowercase characters, digits and separators. A separator is defined as a period, one or two underscores, or one or more dashes. A name component may not start or end with a separator.
>
> A tag name may contain lowercase and uppercase characters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

Tests are [here](https://regex101.com/r/hP8bK1/1).

Comment: any explanation about how this regex come from?

Comment: I read the docs, crafted something I thought would work, then tested all of the edge cases I could think of against the actual tool.  A better approach would have been to look at the source code to see how the string is being parsed, then replicate that logic in a regex.

Answer (score 4):

To be precise, the question and almost all the answers have nothing to do with the docker image tag, but rather with the entire docker image name.

The regular expression for the image tag is much simpler:

/[a-zA-Z\d_][a-zA-Z\d-_.]{0,127}/

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/):

> A tag name may contain lowercase and uppercase characters, digits, underscores,
> periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a
> maximum of 128 characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
(?:[a-z]+/)?([a-z]+)(?::[0-9]+)?
```

But you need to read the spec to replace a-z and 0-9 to all possible characters.

Alternatively, this regex will capture the container name without regard for the specification other than `/` and `:`:

```
(?:.+/)?([^:]+)(?::.+)?
```

Sample data and test

```
def s = [
    'registry.example.com/org/image-name',
    'registry/org/image-name',
    'registry/image-name',
    'image-name',
    'registry.example.com/org/image-name:version',
    'registry/org/image-name:version',
    'registry/image-name:version',
    'image-name:version',
]

s.forEach {
    def image = (s =~ "(?:.+/)?([^:]+)(?::.+)?")[0][1]
    println image
    assert image == 'image-name'
}
```

Will output:

```
image-name
image-name
image-name
image-name
image-name
image-name
image-name
image-name
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution to this problem which contains all varieties and does not use lookaheads.

```golang
// image/tag:v1.0.0
// 123.123.123.123:123/image/tag:v1.0.0
// your-domain.com/image/tag
// your-domain.com/image/tag:v1.1.1-patch1
// image/tag
// image
// image:v1.1.1-patch
// ubuntu@sha256:45b23dee08af5e43a7fea6c4cf9c25ccf269ee113168c19722f87876677c5cb2
// etc...
const dockerImageVerify = "^(([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9])\\.)*([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9])(:[0-9]+\\/)?(?:[0-9a-z-]+[/@])(?:([0-9a-z-]+))[/@]?(?:([0-9a-z-]+))?(?::[a-z0-9\\.-]+)?$"
```

This covers all cases.

Comment: One of the few answers I see realizing that SHAs are usable in lieu of a label

Comment: lieu.. hahaha!!

Comment: just wondering where can i use a name contains SHAs? i tried `docker build -t ` and `docker tag `. they both refused and indicate digest can being contained.

Answer (score 2):

The best source for the official regular expression would be the [Go implementation for OCI references](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/blob/main/reference/regexp.go) used by Docker itself.

To get the full pattern, we can build and execute the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/distribution/distribution/reference"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", reference.ReferenceRegexp)
}
```

```bash
go mod init foo.example
go mod tidy
go run ./main.go
```

This gives us:

```
^((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:(?:\\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]))+)?(?::[0-9]+)?/)?[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:(?:[._]|__|[-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?(?:(?:/[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:(?:[._]|__|[-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?)+)?)(?::([\\w][\\w.-]{0,127}))?(?:@([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:[-_+.][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)*[:][[:xdigit:]]{32,}))?$
```

The capture groups are image name, image tag, and digest respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think this covers all:

```
const ipRegexStr = '((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))';
const hostnameRegexStr = '((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))';
const tagNameRegexStr = '([a-z0-9](\-*[a-z0-9])*)';
const tagVersionRegexStr = '([a-z0-9\_]([\-\.\_a-z0-9])*)';
const dockerRepoTagRegexStr = `^(${ipRegexStr}|${hostnameRegexStr}/)${tagNameRegexStr}(:${tagVersionRegexStr})?$`;

const dockerTagRegex = new RegExp(dockerRepoTagRegexStr);

console.log(dockerTagRegex.test('11.com/0-2:122--')); //true
console.log(dockerTagRegex.test('192.168.1.2/0---2:232-323-d-')); //true
console.log(dockerTagRegex.test('-0-2')); //false
console.log(dockerTagRegex.test('0-2-')); //false
console.log(dockerTagRegex.test('0-2:-23423')); //false
```

Comment: I think this may be missing the case when port numbers are specified.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another iteration inspired by above answers. Ideally there should be a long-format in the docker-compose file so we don't have to break these up. I'm also not sure if I'm naming things the right way (registry/image/tag:label). I can't vouch for how much it follows spec, whether it is too strict or not strict enough, etc. YMMV.

- this is Python (not JS) so may not apply to most in the devops tooling space
- allows strict uppercase variable names for the image tag labels (`${VAR_NAME}`)
- enforces some sane character limits but I did not research what the spec allows
- this code block is in VERBOSE mode and needs to be wrapped in `re.compile("<block>", re.X)` to allow for comments/whitespace to be removed

```regex
# FIRST we have the registry/image/tag:label format
(?:^
    # registry
    (?:(?P<registry>
        (?:
        # IPv4
        (?P<reg_ip>(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))
        |
        # domain
        (?P<reg_domain>(?:(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{,48}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){,4}(?:[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]{,48}[A-Za-z0-9]))
        |
        # hostname
        (?P<reg_host>([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))
        )
        # port
        (?P<reg_port>:[0-9]+)?
    )
    # registry is optional, and not greedy
    /)??
    (?P<image>[0-9a-z_-]{1,40})
    (?:/
    (?P<tag>[0-9a-z_-]{1,40})
    )?
    # label can be a literal or a variable
    (?::
    (?P<label>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9._-]{1,38}[a-z0-9]|\${[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]{,38}[A-Z0-9]})
    )?
# next we have the digest format
$)|(?:^
(?P<user>[a-zA-Z]\w{,25})
@sha256:
(?P<hashcode>[0-9a-f]{64})
$)
```

Here's a code-hint to render a new image string after changing parts of the parsed image string:

```py
def __str__(self):
    if self.image:
        image_tag = '/'.join(filter(None, (self.image, self.tag)))
        imag_tag_label = ':'.join(filter(None, (image_tag, self.label)))
        return '/'.join(filter(None, (self.registry, imag_tag_label)))
    return f'{self.user}@sha256:{self.hashcode}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java with capture groups, where last group is a version tag or a digest:

```
public static final String registryGroup = "((?:(?=[^:\\/]{1,253})(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)(?:\\.(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-))*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?/)*)";
public static final String imageNameGroup = "((?![._-])(?:[a-z0-9._-]*)(?<![._-])(?:/(?![._-])[a-z0-9._-]*(?<![._-]))*)";
public static final String tagOrDigestGroup = "((?::(?![.-])[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,128})?|(?:@sha256:([0-9a-f]{64})$))";
public static Pattern DOCKER_IMAGE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^" + registryGroup + imageNameGroup + tagOrDigestGroup + "$");
```

[Tests here](https://regex101.com/r/Cx1Kz5/1)

Based on @Joe Hildebrand [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672069/4042829)