# Docker image url validation for django

Tags: python, django, docker, url, docker-image

I want to get docker image URL from the user but URLs can't be acceptable with `models.URLField()` in django.
For example, this URL: `hub.something.com/nginx:1.21`, got an error.
How can fix it?

Comment: That because you have a docker tag and no URL.

Comment: Ok. How can validate?

Comment: Why not use CharField? It places fewer rules on what is a valid input.

Comment: Because I don't want the user can type any string.

Comment: `URLField` is just `CharField` with `URLValidator` as field validation. So if `URLField` does not allow this variation of url, I believe best option would be to use `CharField` with `URLValidator` but slightly modified so it will allow this kind of url, or write your own `RegexValidator` with any regex you want.

Comment: @AdrianKurzeja  like this? `image = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[URLValidator])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class App(models.Model):
    image = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r'^(?:(?=[^:\/]{1,253})(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)(?:\.(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-))*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?/)?((?![._-])(?:[a-z0-9._-]*)(?<![._-])(?:/(?![._-])[a-z0-9._-]*(?<![._-]))*)(?::(?![.-])[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,128})?$',
                message='image is not valid',
                code='invalid_url'
            )
        ]
    )
```

Regex reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672069/12727539) and you can check [matchs](https://regex101.com/r/iJqaTz/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.db import models

# I suggest to move this class to validators.py outside of this app folder 
# so it can be easily accessible by all models
@deconstructible
class DockerHubURLValidator(URLValidator):
    domain_re = URLValidator.domain_re + '(?:[a-z0-9-.\/:]*)'


class ModelName(models.Model):
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[DockerHubURLValidator()])
```

I am not great at regexes but I believe I did it right, when I try new `domain_re` regex, it allows as domain: `.com/nginx:1.21`. The rest of url is handled automatically by django

If there will be another case of regex, or for some reason this regex won't work as I expect, I believe from here you will find a way ;)
Just check the [URLValidator code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/validators.py) and modify accordingly.

PS. Sorry for being late, was out with dog

Comment: Thanks for your code. I fix that with better code.